# php variables for json reply

Tags: php, arrays, json

this is my reply

```
Array ([code] => 202 [message] => Accepted [data] => Array ( [resultMap] => Array ( [D3856~H158] => Array ( [AppDay] => * [HosTown] => Colombo 06 [SpecName] => Physiotherapist/Sports Physiotherapist [HosName] => Revival Healthcare Services (Pvt)-Colombo [SpecializationId] => 333 [HosCode] => H158 [AppDate] => Any [DocName] => MR CHAMARA MATHANGAWEERA [DoctorNo] => D3856 ) ) ) [detailMessage] => Success )
```

now i want to assign variable for this vale and echo in proper way i try this
but it is giving a error msg

Undefined index: DocName

this is my code 
////////////////////////////////////

```
if( $response ){
    if ( isset($result->error) )die( $result->error_message );
    /* Convert json data to array */
    $arr=json_decode( $response, true );
    //print_r($arr);
    foreach($arr['data'] as $data)
    {
        $output="Doctor".$data['DocName']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['SpecName']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['HosName']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['Day']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['Date']."<br/>";
    }
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: please look at the few basic concept of array and accessing array using foreach.

[http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php),
[http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the structure of your array. The values you are looking for are nested withing several arrays:

```
$data = array (
    'code' => 202,
    'message' => 'Accepted', 
    'data' => array ( 
        'resultMap' => array ( 
            'D3856~H158' => array ( 
                'AppDay' => '*', 
                'HosTown' => 'Colombo 06',
                'SpecName' => 'Physiotherapist/Sports Physiotherapist',
                'HosName' => 'Revival Healthcare Services (Pvt)-Colombo',
                'SpecializationId' => 333,
                'HosCode' => 'H158',
                'AppDate' => 'Any',
                'DocName' => 'MR CHAMARA MATHANGAWEERA',
                'DoctorNo' => 'D3856',
            ) 
        ) 
    ),
    'detailMessage' => 'Success'
);
```

To print all values for the first record in `resultMap`:

```
foreach(current($data['data']['resultMap']) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
}
```

You need an additional loop in order to print all records in resultMap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this working fine
 for this fixed array values means below given

```
foreach($arr['data']['resultMap']['D3856~H158'] as $data)
 {
        $output="Doctor".$data['DocName']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['SpecName']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['HosName']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['Day']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['Date']."<br/>";


 }
```

**or**
The changing array values are given the answer

```
foreach($arr['data']['resultMap'] as $data)
 {
        $output="Doctor".$data['DocName']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['SpecName']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['HosName']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['Day']."<br/>";
        $output="Doctor".$data['Date']."<br/>";


 }
```

Comment: Please take the time to add proper code highlighting to make reading easier.